# Python PIL image saving

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm new to PIL library and have some problem.

```
base = Image.open('sam.bmp')
base.save(open('base.bmp', 'w'), 'BMP')
```

when I execute that block of code, saved image is distorted in some strange way.

original image:
[image: original image]

opened and saved image:
[image]

As you can see, I'm not doing any transformations with the image - only load and save. Do you have any clue, why is it working that way?

Comment: What version? PIL or Pillow?

Comment: Funky! I thought `base.save('base.bmp')` would simply work?

Comment: @kindall Pillow 3.1.0

Comment: `'w'` is text mode. BMP is a binary format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Reti43](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2243104/reti43) said, You just need to use `base.save('base.bmp')`

Comment: [Documentation link](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save). Either use the filename, such as `base.bmp`, or open a file in binary mode, such as `open(base.bmp, 'wb')`.

Comment: Don't forget the quotes on `open('base.bmp', 'wb')`

Answer (score 2):

This works :

```
base = Image.open('sam.bmp')
base.save('base.bmp')
```

Comment: @AJK with `base.save(open('base.bmp', 'w'), 'BMP')` I've opened file in text, instead of binary mode